# Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova, sockets, socket.io

I found some interesting code to have my phone manouvre objects in my browser but it's kind of outdated I guess because when I try to run the server code it gives me an error. It says the property 'emit' is undefinded.

at socket.  control.js:54:12
at EmitOne  events.js: 77:13
etc 
etc

Now I did some research and most likely it has something to do with an outdated version of socket.io I had installed (0.9.16) but after that I tried a couple more including the latest (1.4.5) but that did not solve it.

The server does start but as soon as I connect with it using my phone it crashes.

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var socket = require('socket.io');

var app = express();

var server = http.createServer(app).listen((1234), function(){
  console.log("Express server on)");
});

var io = socket.listen(server);

app.get('/index.html', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.get('/controller.html', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/controller.html');
});

app.get('/gyro.html', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/gyro.html');
});

app.get('/cordova-2.0.0.js', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/cordova-2.0.0.js');
});

var nextId = 0;
var display;
var sockets = [];

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){

  socket.on('init', function(data){
    if(data === 0){
      display = socket;
    }
    else{
      sockets[nextId] = socket;
      sockets[nextId].emit('ID', nextId);
      display.emit('newController', nextId);
      nextId++;
    }
  });

  socket.on('input', function(input){
    display.emit('update', input);
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    var socketIndex = sockets.indexOf(socket);

    display.emit('destroy', socketIndex);
    console.log("DESTROY: " + socketIndex);
    sockets.splice(socketIndex, 1);
  });

});
```

Any pointers would be appriciated!

Comment: `display` isn't being initialized to anything, so it's `undefined`. .